# Can we use system environment variable in mstest .runsettings configure file

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mstest, vstest

I have added some variable to PATH, such as

```
set resultPath=C:\Temp\Results
set platform=x64
```

And I want to use this variable in microsoft test configuration file .runsettings. e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
    <RunConfiguration>
        <ResultsDirectory>$(resultPath)</ResultsDirectory>
        <TargetPlatform>$(platform)</TargetPlatform>
    </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
```

I tried both mstest.exes and vstest.console.exe by using configuration .runsettings file as above, but failed. The .trx file was created under .\$(resultpath) folder and one of test cases failed because it need x64 environment binaries to run, the default platform of microsoft test is win32.

Any comment?

My OS is win7, Visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't currently supported but you can vote for it at https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/7491553-unit-test-configuration-file-runsettings-support